# i have this issue where my react components are not rendering despite not changing any configuration on the create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

i'm assuming it's something with the create-react-app update. usually in my previous projects, when inspecting the page i would see each component broken down into its html tags, but now it just shows the name of the component, and the tags which make up the component wont be displayed.

```
//App.js
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import heading from './head';

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
        <heading/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```
//head.js
import React from 'react';

const head = () => {
    return (
        <h1>hello</h1>
    )
}

export default head;
```

this code without changing the create-react-app config would still show the blank page[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aaBYY.png)

Comment: I think it's because you're using lowercase jsx for components which is not supported. change `<heading />` to `<Heading />`

Comment: yea, that worked... thanks

Answer (score 0):

Component names must begin with Capital-case:

```
// rest of imports ...
import Heading from './head';

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
        <Heading/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```